# How to call text field from one class to another in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, protocols

I have an IBOutlet of an text field in one class and i wanted to call that text field into another class.

the code is somewhat of this type:

```
class destinationCreateAlertViewController{

   @IBOutlet weak var addresstf: UITextField!

   class dragging{
     func 1(){
        address = "mumbai"
        adresstf.text = address // this reference of text Field is not getting called
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: you can't use UITextfiled outlet in another class

Comment: How you are calling `dragging` class method ? from where ?

Comment: What do you want to perform with this after access?

Comment: Be specific. From where u want put textfield and from where u want to called?

Comment: Please be specific and describe your problem briefly.

Comment: there is a class inside class.

Comment: `there is a class inside class` Why?! Don't do that unless you have a very good reason.